# Get entry with max value from Map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I cannot understand how to use `maxBy` and `maxWith` methods from *Map* interface. I have this code:

```
var myMap: Map<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()
// ...
var best = myMap.maxBy { ??? }
```

I'd like to get the entry with max value but I don't know what to pass to `maxBy` or `maxWith`.

Comment: If somebody new to kotlin is curious why it is possible to have maxBy function without parentheses (), reason is that when the only function argument is lambda - which is true for maxBy function, then you can omit parentheses and instead of them put directly curly braces with lambda

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## MaxBy

MaxBy converts the values to a comparable type, and compares by the computed value

## MaxWith

MaxWith compares the items with each other and sorts them by the return value of the comparator.

## Which one to use

MaxBy makes more sense usually, because it is usually faster (although YMMV), and because implementations can be simpler, but if the items can only be sorted by comparing then maxWith may be needed.

## How to use it

This gets the highest value entry:

```
var maxBy = myMap.maxBy { it.value }
```

The same code with maxWith would look like this:

```
val maxWith = myMap.maxWith(Comparator({a, b -> a.value.compareTo(b.value)}))
```

Comment: What is MaxBy behavior in case of a tie?

Comment: maxBy is deprecated, it would make sense to update the example to use maxByOrNull.

Comment: It looks like it is not working at all. IntelliJ tells me the following code does not compile for several reason :
`
val MyMap = HashMap<String, Int>
// ... add some data 
val max: Int =
            myMap.maxOfWithOrNull(Comparator({ a, b ->
                a.value.compareTo(b.value)
            }))`

Answer (score 6):

Create a class like below

```
 data class Student(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Now goto Oncreate

```
 val public = listOf(Student("param",29),
            Student("nilesh", 19),
            Student("rahul", 13),
            Student("venkat", 12),
            Student("Ram", 22),
            Student("Sonam", 18))
```

Now for maxBy in Create

```
val maxAge=public.maxBy { p-> p.age }
    println(maxAge)
    println("Student Name: ${maxAge?.name}" )
    println("Student Age: ${maxAge?.age}" )
```

and for minBy in Create

```
val minAge = public.minBy { p->p.age }
    println(minAge)
    println("Student Name: ${minAge?.name}" )
    println("Student Age: ${minAge?.age}" )
```

Comment: is it possible to print age within the same line without taking extra variable(`maxAge/minAge`)